# "Resource not available" error when trying to enable demographic report in Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, error

I want to enable Demographic and Interest Reports in Google Analytics. But whenever I try to do so, this error is shown:

[image]

Does anybody know how to solve this? I've refreshed the page, waited a couple of days and tried again, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

In order to enable that feature you need to have to enable Remarketing and Advertising reporting features and have an active Google Ads account linked with analytics.

For more details see: [Enable Demographics and Interests reports](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2819948) and [Enable Remarketing and Advertising Reporting Features in Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2444872)

Comment: Yes, that's right. But I can't enable that either. It gives Internal Error.

Comment: In that case it sounds like you may need to open a support ticket with Google. There is a little "?" icon at the top right of Google Analytics where you can contact support by email or live chat (on weekdays).